# show keyboard with toolbar on button clicked in ios

Tags: ios, keyboard, uitoolbar

I know how to show keyboard accessory with `UITextField`.

```
textField.inputAccessoryView = keyboardToolBar;
```

But what if I don't have a `UITextField` but a button. How do I show a keyboard that has a toolbar?

The toolbar itself will contain a `UITextField`, which I will have to be first responder programmatically.

But how would that work?

**Update**

```
-(void)createKeyboardToolBar
{
    self.keyboardToolBar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 42)];
    self.textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(8, 6, 250, 30)];
    UIBarButtonItem *textBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:self.textField ];
    UIBarButtonItem *postBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Post" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(postComment)];
    [self.keyboardToolBar setItems: [NSArray arrayWithObjects:textBtn,postBtn,nil]];
    self.textField.inputAccessoryView = self.keyboardToolBar;

}
```

So following the suggestions, I come up with the code above. But when I click the button that is supposed to make `self.textField` the first responder, the call is made, but the keyboard or the toolbar does not appear. (I use NSLog)

Comment: on the click of the button SHow the toolbar Containing the textfield first, then as soon as its visible make the textfield as the first responder

Comment: I struggle with this before returning for help, but the suggestions are not working. I am going to add an update to show my code sample.

Answer (score 0):

for your button add action as  **buttonClicked**. so when you click on the button show keyboard by using **becomeFirstResponder** for your `textfield`.

```
- (void)buttonClicked {

[myTextField becomeFirstResponder];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Alloc the textfield,toolbar globally, and add it to the toolbar.
2. In the button action write the 'become firstresponder' for the textfield.

Here is the solution

```
- (IBAction)keyboardaction:(id)sender {
    self.keyToolbar_.hidden=NO;
    CGRect lframe = self.keyToolbar_.frame;
    lframe.origin.y = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height-<keyboardheight>;
    [self.entryTxfld_ becomeFirstResponder];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                          delay:0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                     animations:^ {
                         self.keyToolbar_.frame = lframe;
                     }completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                     }];

}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    CGRect lframe = self.keyToolbar_.frame;
    lframe.origin.y = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.6
                          delay:0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                     animations:^ {
                         self.keyToolbar_.frame = lframe;
                     }completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     }];
    [textField resignFirstResponder];

    return YES;
}
```

[image]

In the XIB for View add toolbar the bottom and to the toolbar added the textfield.For reference find the image.
[image]

Comment: Maybe "recursion" is the reason this is not working: textField would be both the cause for showing the ToolBar and the Effect of showing the toolbar. Maybe something in iOS is against such dependency cycles.